# How to attach to a nohup process?

Tags: linux, nohup

If I start a process with nohup:

```
nohup WHATEVER &
```

then how can I see it again? I mean how to attach my terminal to it again under Linux, e.g.: Ubuntu 11.04 - just like with the `screen` package.

Comment: I want to run a nohup job and to that already running process run a specific command (e.g. authentication). In fact the ideal solution would be to first run reauth command and the the real job **all under the same nohup process id**. So that the nohup processes never loses the kerberos ticket. So I want to run reauth to an already running nohup session automatically (i.e. without screen or tmux). How does one do that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What do you want to do with it?

As other poster has said, screen is better, you can attach/reattach.

`nohup` does not disconnect from terminal, it makes your app ignore SIGHUP, and (usually) redirects stdout/stderr. Run `jobs` in your terminal. It may just be a background job, and you can bring it back with `fg`. I don't know how to get stderr/stdout once you redirect it.

Comment: Once I close the ssh session, I do not see the process in the list of jobs and cannot `fg` it :-( Is there a remedy to this?

Comment: @LordLoh. no, once you disconnect with nohup, you can not reconnect. if you want to reconnect, try `screen`

Comment: I want to run a nohup job and to that already running process run a specific command (e.g. authentication). In fact the ideal solution would be to first run reauth command and the the real job **all under the same nohup process id**. So that the nohup processes never loses the kerberos ticket. So I want to run reauth to an already running nohup session automatically (i.e. without screen or tmux). How does one do that?

Answer (score 3):

You should have used screen in the first place as it is a lot more flexible than nohup.
But if you want to attach to the process in the same way as screen, this link provides more info : https://serverfault.com/questions/24425/can-i-nohup-screen-an-already-started-process

Basically you can either use `reptyr` as described in the link, or you can use an old script called `screenify`. I found the script here : http://isteve.bofh.cz/~isteve/knowledgebase/articles/screenify.html

Comment: I want to run a nohup job and to that already running process run a specific command (e.g. authentication). In fact the ideal solution would be to first run reauth command and the the real job **all under the same nohup process id**. So that the nohup processes never loses the kerberos ticket. So I want to run reauth to an already running nohup session automatically (i.e. without screen or tmux). How does one do that?